# Computer accessed by stranger through TeamViewer

Tags: teamviewer

I recently had my computer accessed remotely by someone through TeamViewer whom I had never given any of my info too. Unfortunately, I was too hasty and deleted TeamViewer, along with the log file.

All they seemed to do was play around with my BitCoin miner and try to access my BTC wallets. There was no indication of a file transfer either way, in the way of assuming that they didn't exit out of the file transfer window. I do, however, have the connection log.

I have contacted TeamViewer about this user, but what can I do about it? I have their user id, number and what I think is the authentication key. And I have done a system restore, reinstalled and updated TeamViewer and made it highly restrictive.

Only people from my account can connect, file transfer is disabled and connections have to be allowed manually from the computer installed on.

Comment: Welcome. Your question does not appear in the scope of what is allowed to talk about here. You may check the [Help Center](http://security.stackexchange.com/help) before asking.

Comment: Isn't this an incident response as well as risk management, Begueradj? Something, an incident, occurred. This is my response to it. People tried accessing something that may or may not be worth a good amount of money, I'd call that a risk. And if someone somehow is finding IDs, and finding a way to gain access to other people's computers, I'd call that a risk too. And in seeing what I can do with the information I have, I am managing it.

Comment: Teamviewer is a two part process where two parties have to each do something to get the connection to complete. How did they trick you into doing your side of the connection process?

Comment: I think that you've done everything you can do. Tracking down criminals is inadvisable as they tend to be criminals. Not running TeamViewer will make things more secure tho at a cost of functionality.

Comment: Fiasco Labs, the issue is, they didn't. I was asleep when this occurred, so I have no idea how this happened.
Neil, yes, criminals are usually criminals. I did a system restore, I'm scanning all of my drives incase they put something on here. I reinstalled TeamViewer with a whitelist containing only my account, and the ID used on the blacklist. Also using a much more secure password.

Comment: "what can I do about it?" is too broad to answer. What to do about what? About preventing other connections? About punishing the attacker? About cleaning up your system? About finding out how they were able to connect in the first place? For this to be 'incident response' or 'risk management', you need to define both the incident or the risk.

Comment: Mainly just want to figure out how they were able to connect without getting my approval to connect, and how to punish them. The account they used is still active, so hopefully they stupidly did this with an actual account that they use, so TeamViewer can actually  do something about the user. The risk is clearly stated. They tried to take money from me through my cryptocurrency wallets, and they could have put malicious software onto my computer. The incident is also clearly stated, as I can't really go anymore in depth because of the limited information I have due tp the log file being gone.

Comment: If this is so off topic, delete it.